# Is this call-by-reference?

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, call-by-value

I have an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList ReceivedPackets = new ArrayList();
```

And I have another ArrayList:

```
ArrayList returnList = ReceivedPackets;
```

Why does **returnList** loose it's value when I run this code?

```
ArrayList ReceivedPackets = new ArrayList();  // ReceivedPackets is empty
ReceivedPackets.Add(1);                       // Now it has an Integer
ArrayList returnList = ReceivedPackets;       // Call-by-Reference (I thought), returnList now has an Integer
ReceivedPackets.clear();                      // returnList is empty now. Why?
```

Comment: `ArrayList` is reference type

Comment: `ReceivedPackets` and `returnList` are two reference variables which point to the same object in memory.  Modifications to that object will be reflected in both.

Comment: How can I do without returnList loosing it's value?

Comment: ``ArraList.Copy()`` method you have to use or ``ArrayList returnList = new ArrayList(ReceivedPackets);``

Comment: Side note: "call by reference" usually implies a method call... There is none in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
ArrayList returnList = ReceivedPackets;
```

You are creating a new *variable* called `returnList`, but this variable points to the same in-memory *object* as `ReceivedPackets`.  There is still only one actual `ArrayList`, it just has two variables pointing to it.  So changes made to one are reflected in both.

> How can I do without returnList loosing it's value?

Create a new object.  At its simplest, that would look like this:

```
ArrayList returnList = new ArrayList();
```

If you also want that object to contain all the values from `ReceivedPackets`, fortunately `ArrayList` has a constructor overload which does just that:

```
ArrayList returnList = new ArrayList(ReceivedPackets);
```

Now you'd have two objects which should contain copies of the same data.  Changes to one would not be reflected in the other.

---

In the absence of that constructor, `ArrayList` also has some `CopyTo()` methods which can be used to copy elements from one to the other.  Failing that, you could also manually loop over the source `ArrayList` and copy elements to the destination `ArrayList`.

It's *possible* that this can get pretty confusing if the `ArrayList` itself *contains* reference objects.  Because those too may have multiple "pointers" to the same in-memory object.

For example, if you create a single `Widget` object and add it to two `ArrayList` objects, then any modifications made to the `ArrayList` objects (adding/removing elements) would be independent, but any modification made to the `Widget` object would be reflected in both `ArrayList`s.

The point is that the `ArrayList` *itself* is an object, independent of the objects it contains.

So, depending on the full context of what you're doing, your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` is a reference type, meaning that if you simply assign some variable to an instance of it, both objects will point to the same location in memory.

If you want to create deep copy, create a new object.

```
static void Main() {
    ArrayList a = new ArrayList() {1,2,3};
    var b = a;
    var c = new ArrayList(a);

    a.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine(a.Count); // 0
    Console.WriteLine(b.Count); // 0
    Console.WriteLine(c.Count); // 3
}
```